# What exactly does avconvert do with multiPass and disableFastStart parameters?

Tags: terminal, big-sur, mp4

I don't understand exactly what the `avconvert —multiPass` and `—disableFastStart` parameters do.

Reading the manpage didn't get me any further.

Thank you for an answer

Comment: It states in the _manual page_ what each of those _options_ do. What do you not understand about **--disableFastStart** Disable fast-start movie creation. Reduces disk accesses if fast-start is not required. & **--multiPass** Perform a higher quality multi-pass encode in the conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `-multiPass` option means that the program tries to achieve a higher quality encoding by going through the whole movie more than once. Essentially you're making the trade off that you're getting a slightly higher quality output at the expense of taking considerably longer to encode.

Setting the `-disableFastStart` option means that the converted movie won't feature Fast Start. Fast Start means that you can place the movie on a web server and a user can start viewing the movie while downloading. If you disable Fast Start, the user will have to fully download the movie before it can be viewed. The upside is that fewer disk accesses (i.e. less "strain" on the system) is required when Fast Start is disabled.

Comment: So does it mean that "Fast Start" can only be used for watching and downloading at the same time? Does that mean when I set the parameter that the system converts faster?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "can only be used for"? - The feature enables the possibility of watching the movie while downloading it. You are ofcourse free to download the whole thing before watching it.